# Golang help reflection to get values

Tags: reflection, go

I'm very new in Go. I was wondering how do I get value of mappings out of this using Reflection in Go.

```
type url_mappings struct{
    mappings map[string]string
}

func init() {
    var url url_mappings
    url.mappings = map[string]string{
        "url": "/",
        "controller": "hello"}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use reflection? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to let the user have their own mappings, and I will use reflection to loop through to check all the patterns. Like URL_Mappings in Grails. :)

Comment: @toy: I still don't understand why reflection is necessary

Comment: @toy: If in the listen function or whatever, you ask for a `url_mappings` parameter, so in the function, you can access it's `mappings` property with no reflection (and loop trough it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import "reflect"
v := reflect.ValueOf(url)
f0 := v.Field(0) // Can be replaced with v.FieldByName("mappings")
mappings := f0.Interface()
```

`mappings`'s type is interface{}, so you can't use it as a map.
To have the real `mappings` that it's type is `map[string]string`, you'll need to use some [type assertion](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Type_assertions):

```
realMappings := mappings.(map[string]string)
println(realMappings["url"])
```

---

Because of the repeating `map[string]string`, I would:

```
type mappings map[string]string
```

And then you can:

```
type url_mappings struct{
    mappings // Same as: mappings mappings
}
```

Comment: testing  : panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value·Field on ptr Value

Comment: That's because you pass a pointer to `url` instead of `url` itself. If you insist passing a pointer so change *line 2* with this: `v := reflect.ValueOf(url).Elem()`.

Comment: Thanks I decided to use Indirect instead. :)